# What AC is used when a prepared action is used to shoot something thats being thrown?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist, armor-class

If an archer has prepared an action to shoot using a bow/crossbow/... when an alchemist is going to throw a bomb. What kind of check is it to hit the bomb as he is throwing it? I dont think you would use the alchemists AC because he is no longer holding or in possession of the bomb. So would the AC be for something fine (+8) and the standard +10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Unless the GM rules otherwise, an object can't usually be attacked *after* the attacker makes an attack roll but *before* the object deals damage...

That is, when an attack roll is made, it

> represents your attempt to strike your opponent on your turn in a round. When you make an attack roll, you roll a d20 and add your attack bonus. (Other modifiers may also apply to this roll.) **If your result equals or beats the target's Armor Class, you hit and deal damage.**

Emphasis mine. After the attack roll is made, the bomb either hits and deals damage *or* it doesn't hit and may *still* deal damage (because it's a splash weapon). The attack roll determines *if* damage is or isn't dealt not *when*. Presumably, this is to avoid exactly these kinds of situations: determining AC modifiers due to an object's speed and trajectory is the province of *even more* simulationist systems than *Pathfinder* and its ilk, like, for example, *GURPS* (wherein the GM could, indeed, determine the penalty on an attack roll against a launched arrow based on the arrow's size and speed.)

The [Ready](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#ready) action says, in part, that

> The action occurs just before the action that triggers it. If the triggered action is part of another character's activities, you interrupt the other character. Assuming he is still capable of doing so, he continues his actions once you complete your readied action.

So while a Ready action can interrupt the action needed to *create* a bomb or the action needed to *throw* a bomb, there is no action *to* interrupt *after* an attack roll is made but *before* damage is dealt.

#### This GM acknowledges that these rules make some feats of cinematic archery impossible

And that really is too bad. Yes, an archer *should* be able to shoot an object out of the sky with a readied action, and doing so, on its face, doesn't seem particularly unbalanced. (Although the GM must decide how such a house rule interacts with spell effects, like the bead created by the spell [*fireball*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/fireball.html#fireball).) See the section below on *D&D 3.5* feats for one way to handle this.

### ...And, according to the rules, a typical archer can't attack an [alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist)'s [bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Bomb-Su-) before it's thrown, either

But it's actually *worse* than that. Because the bomb is a weapon held by an opponent, rather than following the rules for [Smashing an Object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Smashing-an-Object), the archer must follow the rules for the combat maneuver [sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder), and that combat maneuver can only be made with melee attacks.

The primary way for an archer to sunder using ranged weapon is by acquiring the [fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter) archetype [archer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo---fighter-archetypes/archer)'s level 3 class feature trick shot.

Were the archer to employ such a method, he'd use the standard rules for the combat maneuver sunder then apply whatever rules allowed the ranged sunder and then, if successful, typically deal half damage to the bomb (because ranged weapon attacks usually deal half damage to objects) in an attempt to break the vial that is a [bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/delayed-bomb) (likely having hardness 1 and 1 hit point as per a [potion vial](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions)).

#### That the typical ranged combatant can't sunder at range is probably a good thing

Were a ranged combatants able to sunder worn items *without* devoting resources to doing so, they'd routinely make sunder attempts against [holy symbols](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/toys-games-puzzles#TOC-Holy-Symbol) and [spell component pouches](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/containers-bags-boxes-more#TOC-Pouch) in addition to making sunder attempts against enemy archers' bows and footmen's spears. However, for some campaigns, this would make clerics and wizards slightly more balanced (and paranoid!), but the GM absolutely should give players considering playing such classes a heads up *first* before instituting such a house rule.

---

### A few useful feats from *Pathfinder*'s antecedent *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*

- The untyped feat **Deflect Ranged Attack** (*Dragon* #274 60) has the prerequisites Dex 13, Point Blank Shot, Precise Shot, Ranged Disarm (*CW* 30), and base attack bonus +5 or higher. The feat allows the user to take the ready action and, when applicable, make a ranged attack to deflect and damage one in-flight thrown dagger (AC 23), arrow (AC 25), or crossbow bolt (AC 28).
- The general feat **Ranged Sunder** (*Complete Warrior* 104) has the prerequisites Str 13, Point Blank Shot, Precise Shot, and base attack bonus +5. The feat allows making ranged sunder attempts against targets within 30 ft.

Comment: Thank you for the nice break down.The player who has the alchemist knows that is bombs are fair game. I just had this idea and was working on how feasible it was. Now I wont be shooting every bomb, but getting the occasional bomb to blow up in his face would be nice. 3.5 material is not helpful.

Comment: @Fering You're welcome. I think that having the bombs blow up prematurely would be a house rule, though. Would you prefer I omit the *3.5* stuff? I thought the Deflect Ranged Attack feat, for example, might provide a point of comparison if you wanted to construct your own house rules. (And, of course, *Pathfinder* is *3.5* compatible. `:-)` )

Comment: If I start using 3.5 material as the DM, then that gives the players leeway to ask if they can. Ive only just opened up using more pathfinder material so I really want to avoid that.

Comment: @Fering That's fair. If it's okay, I'll leave it in just in case it helps someone else with a similar question.

Comment: I have no problems with it being left in for others.

Comment: I considered mentioning Sunder in my answer but I thought it was irrelevant due to it being melee-only. I completely forgot about the Fighter feature that allows you to make ranged Sunder attempts. Kudos for mentioning.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc *And* I thought your suggested workaround of using the rules for called shots was rather elegant (if difficult to accomplish). So, hey, kudos, too.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if the alchemist were *holding* the bomb, it would be easy to use the variant [Called Shot](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/variants/calledShots.html) rules (edit: more likely, ranged Sunder feature from the Fighter class; thanks @HeyICanChan) for a hand shot. Unfortunately that's not the case.

So, as you pointed out, we have a Fine object, which adds +8 AC, and it's made out of glass, which gives it 1 hardness. It'll likely have just 1 hitpoint (unless the vial is more than an inch thick). Of note is this additional rule about attacking objects:

> An object's Armor Class is equal to 10 + its size modifier (see Table: Size and Armor Class of Objects) + its Dexterity modifier. An inanimate object has not only a Dexterity of 0 (–5 penalty to AC), but also an additional –2 penalty to its AC. Furthermore, if you take a full-round action to line up a shot, you get an automatic hit with a melee weapon and a +5 bonus on attack rolls with a ranged weapon.

It's unclear whether the AC penalties mentioned are already factored in to the 10 + 8. On the one hand, why would the author make the reader do more arithmetic for no reason? Surely they included those penalties just to bring granularity to the rules and assist weird or rare rulings involving objects. On the other hand, I've seen much, much stupider writing in rulebooks before, and I'm actually inclined to say that we need to do the math based on the fact that they mentioned it at all. So with the penalties mentioned, you'd actually be looking at an **AC of 11.**

EDIT: Thinking about it a little harder, those penalties to AC are based on a 0 Dexterity score and I imagine the -2, despite being unlabelled, is due to the assumption that the object isn't trying to move at all -- much like the -2 penalty given for being stunned. Really, they are both based on movement, because AC derived from Dexterity is based on the assumption that the target will actually try to avoid being hit. Definitely room for interpretation for a higher AC score if you want to impose that on your players. If you want to ignore the existing system completely and just use an AC that's supposed to be balanced, the ACs given by the "Deflect Ranged Attack" Feat for D&D 3.5 (again, thanks @HeyICanChan) seem like a good starting point.

The other thing is ruling whether or not your archer can actually take the full-round action. The rules seem to imply that you use the full-round action to "line up the shot," but it doesn't say whether you use an additional action next round to actually shoot. Since your archer has to time his shot with the alchemist throwing the bomb, and full-round actions can't be delayed, this is kind of weird. I personally would rule that the archer can use a full round action a round in advance to aim (basically have his bow drawn) and then use a prepared action to snipe the bomb when it's thrown with the bonus. On the other hand, it makes sense to rule that the archer doesn't have a full round to aim at the bomb while it's flying in mid-air. So it can really go either way.

> Ranged Weapon Damage: Objects take half damage from ranged weapons (unless the weapon is a siege engine or something similar). Divide the damage dealt by 2 before applying the object's hardness.

So your archer is going to need to deal at least 4 damage to break the vial.

So as the rules provide it, it's an 11 to hit and you need to deal 4 damage on the hit, with an option to get a +5 bonus by aiming a round in advance (that part is open to interpretation a little). There isn't anything I can find about moving objects. I think that might be left up to you as the GM. You should consider whether the alchemist is a friend or a foe; an ally alchemist would be able to coordinate with the archer and throw his bomb in a predictable arc to make it easy, but a foe alchemist obviously wouldn't do that. However, on the other hand, it's unlikely that the foe alchemist would expect this maneuver, so it's unlikely that he'll be throwing "curveballs."

Comment: Basically the bomb will be targeted once it becomes "active" so that it can explode. Since the rules are not clear on the exact moment this happens, I simply used the last part of the process, the throwing, as to when it should be hit for this effect instead of before.